# Using newtypes in diesel columns

Tags: rust, newtype, rust-diesel

I am using newtypes like `struct GuildId(i64);` for the columns in my diesel model structs. Currently I am implementing these traits:

```
#[derive(Debug, Display, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash, serde::Serialize)]
pub struct $name(pub i64);

impl AsExpression<BigInt> for $name { /* delegate to <i64 as AsExpression<BigInt> */ */ }

impl<ST, DB: Backend> Queryable<ST, DB> for $name
where i64: FromSql<ST, DB> { /* also delegate to i64 */
```

However, when I try to use this type in the following model structs:

```
#[derive(Associations, Identifiable, Queryable)]
#[belongs_to(Guild)]
struct Channel {
    guild_id: GuildId,
    // other fields
}

#[derive(Identifiable, Queryable)]
struct Guild {
    id: GuildId,
    // other fields
}
```

`Channel` still does not implement `BelongingToDsl`. When I try to cast it to the trait, it fails to compile with the following message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `diesel::query_builder::select_statement::SelectStatement<webcord_schema::schema::channels::table>: diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<webcord_schema::schema::channels::columns::guild_id, &webcord_schema::models::GuildId>>` is not satisfied
  --> src/index/guild.rs:23:32
   |
23 |                 let channels = <models::Channel as BelongingToDsl<&models::Guild>>::belonging_to(&guild)
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<webcord_schema::schema::channels::columns::guild_id, &webcord_schema::models::GuildId>>` is not implemented for `diesel::query_builder::select_statement::SelectStatement<webcord_schema::schema::channels::table>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <diesel::query_builder::select_statement::SelectStatement<F, S, D, W, O, L, Of, G, LC> as diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<Predicate>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::filter_dsl::FilterDsl<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<webcord_schema::schema::channels::columns::guild_id, &webcord_schema::models::GuildId>>` for `webcord_schema::schema::channels::table`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `webcord_schema::models::GuildId: diesel::expression::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/index/guild.rs:23:32
   |
23 |                 let channels = <models::Channel as BelongingToDsl<&models::Guild>>::belonging_to(&guild)
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::expression::Expression` is not implemented for `webcord_schema::models::GuildId`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::Expression` for `&webcord_schema::models::GuildId`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>` for `&webcord_schema::models::GuildId`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::belonging_to_dsl::BelongingToDsl<&webcord_schema::models::Guild>` for `webcord_schema::models::Channel`
```

What traits am I missing?

Comment: `BelongingToDsl` trait needs a type parameter. I'm not experienced with diesel but perhaps it's `BelongingToDiesel<Guild>`?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put that. But it still has the requirements below

Comment: I updated the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is not related to `BelongingToDsl`, but to the incomplete implementation of the custom new type wrapper.

As the error message indicates you are missing a trait impl for your new type wrapper:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `webcord_schema::models::GuildId: diesel::expression::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/index/guild.rs:23:32
   |
23 |                 let channels = <models::Channel as BelongingToDsl<&models::Guild>>::belonging_to(&guild)
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::expression::Expression` is not implemented for `webcord_schema::models::GuildId`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::Expression` for `&webcord_schema::models::GuildId`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::BigInt>` for `&webcord_schema::models::GuildId`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::query_dsl::belonging_to_dsl::BelongingToDsl<&webcord_schema::models::Guild>` for `webcord_schema::models::Channel`
```

The interesting line is the second line in `= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of diesel::expression::AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::BigInt> for '&webcord_schema::models::GuildId`. This means you need to add at least an `AsExpression<_>` impl for a reference to your new type wrapper.

So now general speaking: There is [this test case](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/066bc412d7ead423e71de811b1dac9428a63712c/diesel_tests/tests/custom_types.rs#L9-L47) showing how to implement custom types in general. You will see that the custom type on rust side uses two custom derives (`AsExpression` and `FromSqlRow`) that are basically implementing the traits you've already implemented manually and additionally the missing ones. Additionally a `ToSql`/`FromSql` impl is required to describe how the type should be translated into/from a sql type.

Summing that up your type definition should probably look like:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Display, Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash, serde::Serialize, AsExpression, FromSqlRow)]
#[sql_type = "diesel::sql_types::BigInt")]
pub struct $name(pub i64);

impl<DB> ToSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, DB> for $name 
where DB: Backend,
    i64: ToSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, DB>,
{
    fn to_sql<W: Write>(&self, out: &mut Output<W, DB>) -> serialize::Result {
        <i64 as ToSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, DB>>::to_sql(&self.0, out)
    }
}

impl<DB> FromSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, DB> for $name 
where DB: Backend,
    i64: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, DB>
{
    fn from_sql(bytes: Option<&DB::RawValue>) -> deserialize::Result<Self> {
        <i64 as FromSql<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, DB>>::from_sql(bytes).map($name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not accepting the answer for a long time. I stopped working on that project so I haven't verified your answer yet. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: `#[sql_type = "diesel::sql_types::BigInt"]` is the thing missing from the Diesel docs pages on [ToSql](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/serialize/trait.ToSql.html) and [FromSql](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html).

Comment: @M.Leonhard: That's not surprising, because neither trait is related to this attribute. It's [used by the `AsExpression` derive](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/expression/trait.AsExpression.html).

Comment: ToSql and FromSql are related enough that their docs say to add `#[derive(AsExpression)]`.  But they do not say "and also add this sql_type attribute" or "check the AsExpression docs for special requirements."  The AsExpression derivation error message does not say "missing sql_type attribute".  So it's quite easy for users to miss the critical info and waste a lot of time searching for a solution.